# Checking for an input username within a list box to display error message if the username is not unique

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, contains

I am working on a project where I must display an *error message* if the `username` being input is *not unique*. I am attempting to  search within my `Listbox` to see if the username already exists. The program is running fine, but it does not work (find **never** `== true` even when the `username` I'm inputting is the *exact same* as another within my `Listbox`) I am pretty new to C# so I'm kind of just messing around with syntax but nothing seems to be working. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
    private void txt_Username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bool find = lb_Form1_ListUsers.ContainsFocus.Equals(txt_Username.Text);

        if (find == true)
        {
           lbl_Form1_UniqueError.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_Form1_UniqueError.Visible = false;
        }

        find = false;
    }
```

Comment: `bool find = lb_Form1_ListUsers.Text.Equals(txt_Username.Text);`? Since `ContainsFocus` being of type `bool` never equals to `string` (`txt_Username.Text`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ContainsFocus` returns `true` / `false` depending on if `lb_Form1_ListUsers` has or not *keyboard focus*; so 
comparing this `bool` value with `string` `txt_Username.Text` *doesn't have much sence*.

Assuming that `lb_Form1_ListUsers.Items` contains values of type `String` (user names) we can *query* them if there's `Any` equals to `txt_Username.Text`

```
   using System.Linq; 

   ...

   private void txt_Username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     bool find = lb_Form1_ListUsers
       .Items
       .Cast<String>() //TODO: put the right type here if required
       .Any(item => item == txt_Username.Text);

     lbl_Form1_UniqueError.Visible = find;  
   }
```